# XSLT: Difference between <xsl:element name="a"> and <a>

Tags: xml, xslt

if I'm writing an XSLT, is there any difference between

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="a"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="/*/y">
    <a><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: No there's no difference in them.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, no, there is no difference, and I suggest using the `<a>` version as it is clearer and more concise.

The time to use `<xsl:element>` is when the element's name, namespaces or both need to be determined dynamically, for example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
   <xsl:element name="myNewItem{position()}">
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This will produce `<myNewItem1>`, `<myNewItem2>`, `<myNewItem3>`, etc. in the output.

When the element names are predetermined in your XSLT, then it's usually cleaner to avoid `xsl:element`.

Answer (score 3):

There is one difference, which is that with a literal result element (`<a>`) namespaces are copied from the stylesheet, which does not happen with `xsl:element`. If you use literal result elements, you may need to stop unwanted namespaces being copied to the result by use of `exclude-result-prefixes`.

Some people seem to use xsl:element habitually in preference to literal result elements, and I have never understood why. It's sometimes the same people who complain about XSLT being verbose. If you know the element name statically, my habit is to use a literal result element every time.